# Odd Window appears when I lose connection, 'Unable to load Page'

Tags: system, capnet-assist

Everytime I lose my internet connection, this window appear on the screen:

[image]

When the connection is reestablished, the windows closes itself if I click on try again. I can close the window any time too

What is this window? And why it appears?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is the [Captive Network Assistant](https://launchpad.net/capnet-assist) (CapNet Assist). It attempts to find out if your network traffic is being caught in a captive network portal (like what you find in the airport or a coffee shop) and assist you in logging in to this captive network. elementary is still ironing out a few issues with how and when it decides to appear.

If CapNet Assist is showing up unexpectedly, please check [in Launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/capnet-assist) to make sure that this case has already been reported. If it hasn't been reported, please make a new report describing the situation in which it appears by following the elementary [bug reporting guide](https://elementary.io/docs/code/reference#reporting-bugs).

Comment: It has been reported, https://bugs.launchpad.net/capnet-assist/+bug/1459903, thanks!

Comment: Is there any way to disable this feature?

Answer (score 5):

I have faced this issue when working with static network profiles in Elementary OS Freya 0.3 and switching between local networks without a public gateway. Like Daniel had mentioned, this is a Captive Portal Assist which allows users to connect to public WiFi hotspots and immediately traps in a minimalistically launched Midori browser to complete certain procedures to connect to the Internet.

After digging through some links, I did find an [external article](http://zaantar.eu/2015/08/disable-captive-portal-detection-on-elementary-os-freya/?lang=en) that presents a solution to disable this functionality.

Essentially, it asks you to run this command:

```
sudo chmod -x /etc/NetworkManager/dispatcher.d/90captive_portal_test
```

Disclaimer: Although this solves the issue for me, I do not fully understand its implications. Please use it at your own discretion.

Article credit: Zaantarovo

Comment: It removes the executable rights from `90captive_portal_test`. Nothing too dangerous :)

Answer (score 2):

> Disclaimer: Although this solves the issue for me, I do not fully understand its implications. Please use it at your own discretion.

In reference to Arvaind Asuri Balaji answer (who then referenced an article by Zaantarovo)

Here's my newbie take on what the command does, piece by piece:

- sudo = root command
- chmod = change mode
- -x makes it **not** executable(?) (+x would make a file executable)
- `/etc/NetworkManager/dispatcher.d/90captive_portal_test` is the file that controls/dictates the odd window

so it shouldn't be anything *too* bad
and besides just the run the command again but replace `-x` with `+x` if things do mess up