# Can I safely remove capnet-assist package?

Tags: capnet-assist

I want to remove this package, because for some reason, elementary OS makes my router reboot. I am sure the cause is elementary OS, because it only happens when using elementary OS on any PC in the house, I can't explain why, but I can see this pattern for months.

When the router reboots, [this window](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/361/odd-window-appears-when-i-lose-connection-unable-to-load-page) appears, this is a home computer, so I don't need this feature.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes you can safely remove it. The purpose of the capnet-assist package is to:

> Assists users in connective to Captive Portals such as those found on
>   public access points in train stations, coffee shops, universities,
>   etc.
>
> Upon detection, the assistant appears showing the captive portal. Once
>   a connection is known to have been established, it dismisses itself.

So removing it will only take away the ability to automatically display a  Captive Portal's login page when you connect to a wifi network (which is not really a must have).

However, you may still want to report a [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/capnet-assist) so that developers can investigate the issues that you are seeing.